# Flex 4.5 Mobile Login Form needs 2 clicks?

Tags: android, apache-flex, forms, authentication

I have been working on developing an application for the android market thta firstly requires the users to login to a account. I have put the code together below, along with a data link to a database in order to check the credentials. However the application does not switch to the second view on the first click of the "Login" button however it seems to take 2 or more clicks sometimes. I presume as it is fetching data from a database that it takes time to be verifies, could someeone tell me how to solve this and maybe implement a BusyIndicator along with it?

```
<![CDATA[
           protected function login_btn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
           {
                var match:Boolean;

                getEmployeesByNameResult.token = employeeService.getEmployeesByName(usr_nme_txtbox.text, pass_txtbox.text);

                if (getEmployeesByNameResult.lastResult != null)
                {
                     navigator.pushView(HomeView, getEmployeesByNameResult.lastResult.id);
                }
           }
      ]]>



<s:Button id="login_btn" width="100%" label="Login"
                            click="login_btn_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

showBusyIndicator is a property on the main service classes used in Flex apps.  I would expect it to also work on Android, in theory, but in practice I'm not sure mobile app will have a mouse cursor.  You should be able to work something out to have some animated "Wait" object.

What service class are you using?  ( HTTPService; RemoteObject; or WebService? )

I'll point out that the service classes in Flex are asynchronous; not synchronous like your code tries to use it.  So, when you run this code:

```
getEmployeesByNameResult.token = employeeService.getEmployeesByName(usr_nme_txtbox.text, pass_txtbox.text);

if (getEmployeesByNameResult.lastResult != null)
{
    navigator.pushView(HomeView, getEmployeesByNameResult.lastResult.id);
}
```

your getEmployeesByNameResult.lastResult value is most likely null; unless your service call has 0 process time and 0 latency (Both are unlikely).  You should listen for the result event on the service:

```
protected function login_btn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 var match:Boolean;

 getEmployeesByNameResult.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, onResult);
 getEmployeesByNameResult.showBusyCursor = true;
 getEmployeesByNameResult.token = employeeService.getEmployeesByName(usr_nme_txtbox.text, pass_txtbox.text);

}

protected function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void
{
 if (getEmployeesByNameResult.lastResult != null)
 {
   navigator.pushView(HomeView, getEmployeesByNameResult.lastResult.id);
 }                
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that seems to have done the trick just my own stupid fault for forgetting the Async in Flex Mobile apps. :-)

Comment: @user723858 Glad this helped; Be sure to mark it as the correct answer. You'll get some Karma points; I'll get some Karma points, and future people who find this question will have the confirmed solution.